# Using HTML as a GUI for Python 3

Tags: html, python-3.x

Hi so i was wondering if there was anyway to use a webbrowser as an interface for a python script on the same computer. Basically i would like to be able to run a python script. It would open a webbrowser and have like buttons or text boxes and whatever i put in there activates functions in the python script. I am using this cause i want to try and use the google speech recognition that can added to a text box in a webpage to enter text into a python script. Let me know if you guys have any ideas. Thanks. Also i'm not an expert so please leave example code if you can.

Comment: You'll need to learn first how a webserver with server-sides script work before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Check these two libraries:

http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/webbrowser.html
and 
http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex50.html